# Is there a way to specify position of R gwidget window on screen?

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

I was wondering if there is a way to say where something like this:

```
require(gWidgets)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")
win <- gwindow()
```

appears - more precisely is there a way to say that the window should appear on screen at x-pixel 0 and y-pixel zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing a position to the parent argument of `gwindow`, as in `gwindow("title", parent=c(200, 200))`.

Comment: actually, no. the windows follow there own logic of placement and do not bother with my parent parameter. Do I have a bug?

Comment: win7 64bit on all three pcs ... I played around a little more and it seems to be a strange/funny combination of some possition the window gets to be cascaded with the R window and previous windows and whatever I put into the parent parameter. so the parent parameter does something but the reference isn't the screen but the other windows (btw. cool package)

Comment: Interesting. I can't replicate on my test setup, but I have windows 8, not 7. Not sure I can offer much. If you want to try some things, the basic call can be played around with using RGtk2 commands: `require(RGtk2); getToolkitWidget(win)$move(300, 400)`.

Comment: ... but only when visible is set to T `visible(win)<-T`

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing that out. I'll look for a workaround in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure I can work around this: somethings are determined by the window manager, this is only a request: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-move